# How to install gdb in unix without root access

Tags: unix, gdb

I am trying to install gdb in unix but i don't have root access to create files and directories in root folder. However i can only create folders in my own directories. I have followed this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/installing_gdb.htm but every time execution fails at step 4 because it needs to create files at root level. How do I fix it?

```
Step1:
$ build> gzip -d gdb-6.6.tar.gz 
$ build> tar xfv gdb-6.6.tar 
$ build> cd gdb-6.6 
Step2:
$ gdb-6.6> .⁄configure 
Step3:
$ gdb-6.6> make
Step4:
$ gdb-6.6> make install 
**execution fails at this point.
```

Or is there any other solution to install gdb in unix without root level access. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you  `./configure`, you can specify `--prefix` which control whether software is installed.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/gdb
make
make install
```

Above will install gbd under `$HOME/gdb`.

You need to specify `$HOME/gdb/bin/gdb` to run the program after installation. Or adjust `$PATH` to include `$HOME/gdb/bin`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/gdb/bin
```

Comment: thanks that solved my problem..though I got other errors like makeinfo not found.. but gdb is installed in the respective directory..

Comment: @user040891, Could you post a separated question with error message?

Comment: @user040891 gdb will build even when certain support packages aren't present, with reduced functionality. For example, if `configure` can't find `Python.h`, it won't build the python scripting extensions. If `makeinfo` isn't found, the info files in the `doc` directory won't be made.

Comment: Initially gdb was installed but after restarting my system when i tried to use it, gdb was not found in same directory.. How can i solve this problem? Do i need to do whole installation again?

Comment: @user040891, Is your directory wiped out when your restart? BTW, if you can restart, isn't it under your control? You should have root access.

Comment: no, it does not wipe out..all other files and directories are present. But i am facing problem with gdb. And I don't have root access..i tried to create files separately but was denied access.

Comment: @user040891, Did you try `sudo make install`?

Comment: i tried to.. but access denied. and now even with the same whole process i cant install gdb.can u suggest any other way?

Comment: @user040891, How about change directory: `./configure --prefix=/path/to/another/directory`

Comment: @user040891, You can put it into your shell initialization file: `$HOME/.bashrc` for example (bash).

Comment: @user040891, No problem. Happy debugging :)